# Sublayers do not exist or are not supported in the geoprocessing tool?

Tags: arcpy, error-000732, group-layer

I'm trying to batch export selected layers that I drag and drop in the tool that I've created by a selecting feature class. It's working when features are input from the source and layers in TOC. However, you get an error when the layers are in group layers. "Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset 'Topography layers\Linear' does not exist or is not supported"

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import arcpy, os, sys

try:
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

        def selectExport (Layer, LyrSelected, outName):

                for fc in inFeatures:
                        Layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "outlayer")
                        LyrSelected = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Layer,"INTERSECT",SelectLyr,"","NEW_SELECTION")
                        result = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(LyrSelected).getOutput(0)) 
                        if result > 0:
                                if fc.endswith(".shp"):
                                        bName= fc.split(".")[0]
                                        outName = os.path.join(outPath, os.path.basename(bName))
                                        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(LyrSelected, outName)
                                else:
                                        outName = os.path.join(outPath, os.path.basename(fc))
                                        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(LyrSelected, outName)
                                arcpy.AddMessage("*******Geoprocessing done successfully!*******")
                        else:
                                arcpy.AddMessage("*******No features were selected*******")

except:
        tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
        tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
        pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n     " +        str(sys.exc_type) + ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"
        msgs = "ARCPY ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"

        arcpy.AddError(msgs)   
        arcpy.AddError(pymsg)

        print msgs
        print pymsg

        arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages(1))

        print arcpy.GetMessages(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    outPath = ""
        arcpy.env.workspace = outPath
        inFeatures = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0).split(";")
        SelectLyr = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
        outPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

        selectExport (inFeatures, SelectLyr, outPath)
```

Comment: I'd say test the input first, e.g. split it by "\' and if length of output ==2, it is most likely sitting in the group. Alternatively just move them outside the group Ctrl-Drag helps to create a clone quickly

Comment: @FelixIP thanks. But there are a lot of already set up map templates with layers and sublayers that we use. What I'm after is how I can deal with group and sub layers in the script, 'cos there might be a lot layers involved so I don't want to do that manually.

Comment: If no subgroups in your groups than see 1st part of my comment

Comment: It's because of the space in your group layer name, change to Topography_layers (or similar) and it should work... spaces and punctuation are **bad** in names and paths and you should avoid using them - or suffer the consequences that come back to bite you when you least expect it. That is of course if Linear is a feature layer and not another group layer.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Thanks, that's right, when removing the space it'll work.

Comment: It's a common trap that people fall into... Most of the time a space is OK but just when you're feeling comfortable *snap!* it gets you! It's especially problematic with sys.argv and the like. Paths that contain a space need to be quoted or they're seen as several arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @MichaelMiles-Stimson has mentioned, you can get around this by removing the space in the group layer name.

However as you have mentioned that you have several MXDs and layers already set up, it is a relatively small change to your code (which doesn't seem to touch the space) that will get it working.

The `fc` from `inFeatures` is passing a string like `"'Topography Layers\\Linear'"` (note the extra single quotes `'` in there!) - if you strip out this extra set of single quotes the MakeFeatureLayer tool works:

```
for fcString in inFeatures:
    fc = fcString.strip("'") # Strip out the single quotes
    Layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "outlayer")
```

Oddly, removing the space from the Group Layer name will also overcome this (without the need to remove the single quotes).

---

Alternatively (and possibly the better or more pythonic solution) is to use `arcpy.GetParameter()` instead of `arcpy.GetParameterAsText()`, which passes the layer objects rather than a text string (and then a list via your split).

```
inFeatures = arcpy.GetParameter(0)

for fc in inFeatures:
    Layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "outlayer")
```

This way it doesn't matter about single quotes or spaces in your layer/group layer names.

Comment: Awesome, it's now working with the sub layers as well. Thank you.